# Accessing elements in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have managed to  `subset` and `lapply` a list  of data frames as follows:

```
subsetDeathHA <- 
na.omit(subset(outcome,select = c("Hospital Name", "mortailityRate", "State"), ))

orderSubsetDeathHA <- 
subsetDeathHA[order(subsetDeathHA$"mr" , subsetDeathHA$"Hospital Name", subsetDeathHA$'State'  ),]

splitOrderSubsetDeahtHA <-
split(orderSubsetDeathHA, orderSubsetDeathHA$'State')

aa<- lapply(splitOrderSubsetDeahtHA, function(x) { x[num,] })
```

`num` is the ranking number on a per State basis. 
Using `str(aa)` shows this object is a list of (54) `data.frame`s, where each `data.frame` is one object of 3 variables as follows:

```
List of 54
 $ AK:'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Hospital Name                                            : chr NA
  ..$ mortalityRate                                            : num NA
  ..$ State                                                    : chr NA
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:1986] 4 5 6 10 13 17 19 23 27 28 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1986] "4" "5" "6" "10" ...


 $ AL:'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Hospital Name                                            : chr "D C H REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"
  ..$ mortalityRate                                            : num 15.8
  ..$ State                                                    : chr "AL"
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:1986] 4 5 6 10 13 17 19 23 27 28 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1986] "4" "5" "6" "10" ...
```

What I can't seem to do is the following

1) Subset out the `Hospital Name` and the `State` by removing the `mortalityRate` variable and return a list of the resulting 54 objects/data frames.

2) Place `row.names =F` appropriately  to suppress the indexing that R provides.

3) Even though I thought I had 'na'd out' the `NA` values in the first sub-setting operation,
 when I `print(aa)`, what follows is a sample of the output.

```
$AK
        Hospital Name                                         mr                    State
 NA  NA                                                          <NA>                  NA  <NA>

$AL
        Hospital Name                                          mr                  State
56    D C H REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    15.8                AL
```

etc...

Any help/suggestions appreciated

Comment: It might help if you tag this question with `R`

Comment: You need to `dput` at least AK and AL so that we can test and help. Otherwise, I don't think you ll get any answers here.